# jQuery autocomplete multivalue field like the Google search field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I want to implement a jQuery suggestion multivalue field for the search functionality of my site without comma separated values, but values separated by spaces as Google does.

The field will get a suggestion to complete the word that the user is writing: a search multivalue field.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this: http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/

Comment: Great but I wouldn't the border around the word and space between every words.